Какие контролы использовать в WinForms для открытия в одном окне нескольких текстовых документов?
Давно сидит в голове идея программы для анализа кода (практически с самого начала изучения c#), но в силу недостатка опыта работы с WinForms и дизайнером не могу придумать, какие контролы использовать для этого. Общая идея выглядит примерно так:

Предполагается, что программа будет выполнять поиск в выбранной области на диске (папка проекта) и открывать все файлы с расширением *.cs.
Открываться они будут в виде "плиток", внутри каждой будет код соответствующего файла.
Планируется, чтобы плитки возможно было перетаскивать в произвольное место в окне, при этом если они не мешают соседним, то смогут оставаться в выбранном месте, если же плитка будет помещена поверх соседней, то будет автоматически корректировать свое расположение.
Плитки можно перетаскивать группами, выделив нужные.
Должна быть доступна функция "масштабирования" - пропорциональное увеличение или уменьшение масштаба прокруткой колеса мышки (от общего вида всех плиток, до степени, позволяющей свободно читать код), с центром в точке расположения курсора мышки (как на гугл карте), а также смещения вида перетаскиванием за незанятую область.

Итого.
В программе условно-бесконечный "холст", способный вместить любое количество плиток, и их можно свободно таскать по нему, а также смещать сам холст и масштабировать вид.
Это только то, что относится к представлению, самое интересное (если получится) будет в функциях анализа кода.
Возможно ли реализовать это на WinForms? Если да - подскажите, какие контролы для этого подойдут. Заранее спасибо!
P.S. На скрине изобразил, как это примерно может выглядеть.


Могу дать поверхностный ответ — вам подойдёт RichTextBox с его обширными возможностями управления шрифтом и текстом. А если нужен дополнительный функционал — то помогут пользоваетльские элементы управления, основанные на RichTextBox (или даже не на нём), которые вы можете найти в Интернете. Думаю для больших подробностей вам поможет эта ссылка: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

А для вкладок подходит TabControl. Подробнее тут: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Благодарю, сейчас посмотрю!

MDI (multiple-document interface)

О, круто, спасибо! Каждый документ будет отдельной самостоятельной формой?

Да, именно для этого MDI и используется.
